# How to sort an array in Visual Basic with negatives and repeating numbers?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a code in the console that orders an array, but only if the number is positive, if I enter a negative, it only places it in 0, also, the second array must be empty, but if I put a 0 in the position of the array that is greater at that moment and there is another position with the same number, they both turn to 0, how can I solve these two problems?(I used translate google for this question)

```vb
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim Array(4) As Double 
        Dim Order(4) As Integer 
        Dim j As Integer = 0 
        Dim Higher As Integer 
    
        Console.WriteLine("Type 5 integer.")
    
        For i = 0 To Array.Length - 1 
            Console.Write(i & "> ") 
            Array(i) = Console.ReadLine 
            If Array(i) Mod 1 = 0 Then 
            Else 
                Console.WriteLine("Please, type only a integer.")
                i = i - 1
            End If
        Next
    
        Do While j < 5 
            For i = 0 To 4
                Higher= Max(Higher, Array(i)) 
            Next
    
            For i = 0 To 4
                If Higher = Array(i) Then 
                    Array(i) = 0
                End If
            Next
    
            Order(j) = Higher 
            j = j + 1 
            Higher = -32768 
        Loop
```

Comment: forget about it

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not just calling Array.Sort?